# Alternative voxal app for Ubuntu with Persian language option ( opensource voice Photoshop app )

Tags: software-recommendation

I like to know about alternative app like [voxal](https://www.nchsoftware.com/voicechanger/) as free and opensource voice Photoshop app with Persian language option, voxal introduction could be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9pgjlqsvfs).